# Pass data between 2 native modules (Android NDK)

Tags: android, c, shared-libraries, native, android-ndk

Here is the structure of my program:
- 2 independent modules libA and libB, each one is a single shared library libA.so and libB.so
- A java activity creating 2 threads thA and thB, each one of them calling native JNI functions from one library (thA calling functions from libA.so and thB calling function from libB.so).

I want to pass data of native types (that Java does not know anything about, containing types like pointers that Java can't handle) between both libraries, but I couldn't find any way to make them communicate.

Supossing both libraries know the definition of a native type "typeA", is there a way to pass an object of typeA from libA to libB (preferably without having to copy the data in the VM memory). Pass a memory pointer maybe??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am doing exactly this in an application I'm working on. I allocate memory in libA and return the pointer as a `long` up to Java via JNI. I then call a function in libB that passes the pointer down so it can be accessed.

However, this naive approach has problems. Although it may work sometimes, if libA and libB live on different pages of RAM, touching the pointer in libB may crash the program. The reason reported for the crash may vary on the build and run, making it a difficult situation to debug. Even worse, if the memory allocated partially resides on one page of RAM and partially on another, only when you hit the boundary you will crash whatever lies beyond, and therefore may not detect the problem immediately. I have managed to kill the OS numerous times and produce any number of various errors. If your libraries are small and loaded in adjacent memory, odds are good you will be okay. Native applications on Android can get away with things that vanilla Java apps cannot.

**Solutions:**

1. [Ashmem](http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features#ashmem) will allow you to create a shared memory space between the applications. This may come at a learning curve if you are new to Android development or the Linux OS.
2. You could use a [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) between two applications and stream the data.
3. You could send the data up from libA via [JNI functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) directly to a Java created buffer that must be sized to accommodate the data from libA. You could then once again pass it down via JNI to libB. This solution will be slower and the cost may invalidate the reasons you are using native code to begin with, but it's a good way to debug and discover if your problems are memory-related or inherent to your program's logic.

Answer (score -1):

Passing a pointer to a typeA from A to B may be an option. It depends on the live cycle of typeA in the libraries though. Make sure that the typeA object is not deleted in one library while it's still in use in the other.

One way to pass the pointer is to go over JNI and use a jlong/long to represent the pointer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to switch between threads thA/thB for instance how to run some code on thread thB when thread thA is being active? Also see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667117/updating-ui-from-background-thread-using-ndk-entirely-no-jni.