# Updating UI from background thread using native code entirely (no JNI)?

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am writing an Android application that does much of a processing in the background thread. The calculations are performed in the native code using C++. I want to update UI with the partial results during calculations.

I am able to do so through JNI, namely set reference to UI object in java and then call a method of this object from native code trough JNI. I am looking for a more efficient solution without any JNI calls in the rendering part (the basic setup and an activation entry point will have to be in java).

Is it possible to change execution thread from background to UI entirely in native code without using JNI (only in the rendering part)?

Thanks for your answers. Much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I am considering using OpenGL to render calculated content (sort of video frames) in my view. In that case I would probably want to use `eglSwapBuffers()` method that is available in EGL library from 2.3 onwards. The biggest problem is, I think, how to easily switch from background "calculation" thread to UI "open GL" thread in native code without JNI overhead. What would you recommend? Thanks for your help!

**PSEUDOCODE:**
Here is some pseudocode that helps to illustrate what I want to achieve here. It is more like a threading issue but Android framework comes into play as well.

```
// background thread
void Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz)
{
    //long calculation
    struct result * res = calculate();

    //want to update ui using opengl on ui thread
    updateGL(res);
}


//want to run it on ui thread as opengl can be run only on ui thread
void updateGL(struct result * res)
{
    //some opengl code with "res"
    someGLcodeWithResult(res);

    //render surface
    eglSwapBuffers();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
As the bounty slowly draws to close, one more clarification. There are couple of ways to call the `updateGL` method above. The most typical one is to use `GLSurfaceView` in java code. It would require setting a renderer ([setRenderer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderer%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer%29)) and then overriding [onDrawFrame](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onDrawFrame%28javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10%29) with some code to call JNI/native layer. This way for every frame being rendered one JNI call gets executed.

I would like to do the rendering a little differently. I want to call `updateGL` without using java/JNI code at all and use only the native layer (as presented in the excerpt above). The biggest problem for me now is how to run the `updateGL` on UI thread (required by OpenGL) without the java callback. Is it at all feasible?

Comment: Thanks, good tip, I'll probably end up using a similar rendering mechanism (calling eglSwapBuffer on my own) but using pure NativeActivity is out of the question in my case as I need a complex UI as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem right now. Perhaps this might help:

When you take a look at the STABLE-APIS.html in the latest NDK it says:

### > V. Android-9 Stable Native APIs:

All the APIs listed below are available for developing native code that runs
on Android > 2.3 system images and above.

### The EGL graphics library:

EGL provides a native platform interface to allocate and manage OpenGLES
surfaces. For more information about its features, please see:

```
http://www.khronos.org/egl
```

In a nutshell, this will allow you to do the following directly from
native code:

```
- List supported EGL configurations
- Allocate and release OpenGLES surfaces
- Swap/Flip surfaces for display  (eglSwapBuffers)
```

So if you're targeting Android-9 then you could try to use the EGL lib in native code.
(Let me know if this works :))

Comment: Well, the egl library itself works fine, I am able to initialize egl context, surface etc. all in native code and then draw to the surface using `eglSwapBuffers()`. However, the problem I am facing now is that in order to call this `eglSwapBuffers()` I have to go through java/JNI because OpengGL can be touched only on UI thread. Since my processing is executed in native code in background thread I have to do a switch. My goal is to simply avoid this JNI calls for every frame being rendered due to an added overhead. I hope it is more comprehensible now? :)

Comment: sorry, that I couldn't help. But I have a short question that you might be able to answer. You said that opengl can only be touched on the UI thread. Can you tell me which parts of opengl cannot be used outside the ui-thread? I use opengl in another thread and set up buffers/load textures and stuff. So far I only found out that I cannot draw or use glReadPixel from outside the the ui-thread. But I'm experiencing some weird crashes occasionally while rendering. Perhaps you can help me there.

Comment: This is a hard question to answer without more details. I strongly advise you to open a new SO question. I will investigate it if you link the questions.

Comment: okay I think I have the solution. You don't have to do any GL in the UI-thread. You just have to make sure that everything is done in one thread. In this thread you have to manually set up eglSurface/eglContext. The constructor for the eglSurface takes a surfaceHolder for your surface and this informs the ui-thread about changes automatically.
Take a look at this:
http://e-university.wisdomjobs.com/net/chapter-924-288/using-android-3d-graphics-with-opengl-es.html

It solved my problems, I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that. I read elsewhere that you must do GL rendering in the UI thread. Thanks for letting me know. I'll have a look at my code this week and let you know if that works for me as well.

Comment: Yeah, I moved GL rendering out of UI thread and it all worked. Thanks! My theoretical question still remains though, but only for strictly educational purpose :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking a look at the Mozilla Fennec source. There is a minimal Java/JNI shim that allows rendering on Android, but all the work is done via native code (regular ol' Mozilla code)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Btw, the instructions how to get/build the source are described for instance here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android#Build.

Answer (score 1):

Great thoughts, but try and understand this thing

1. You have code in C++ in native
2. UI in java runs in VM

Now what you are asking is C++ code to interact with UI in Java VM which is another program to communicate. The only way to do it would be some interprocess communication. Having said that, now go figure that out which suits you best. JNI is fast and reliable, since u dont want to go that way, figure out any other IPC that suits you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. From my experience, the NDK code is running in the same process as the java code so I would require proper thread management rather than interprocess communication (correct me if I am wrong). Also, I do not want to get rid of Java part completely. I want to use it for an entry point but do not want to go through java/jni for every frame that is being rendered due to an added overhead. Sorry if I did not make myself clear in the question.

Comment: Inter-process communication (IPC) is a set of methods for the exchange of data among multiple threads in one or more processes. via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: Good, so we're talking about the same thing. Since your answer is a bit vague, have you got an idea how to solve this particular problem?

Comment: Well my suggestion is to stick to JNI if possible. Thats the most efficient mechanism available to interact between Native and Android code

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change execution thread from background to UI entirely in native code without using JNI?

You cannot modify widgets from native code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How does this limitation apply to rendering with OpenGL?

Comment: @youri: You can certainly update OpenGL direct from native code. How threading plays into that, I cannot say.